# Why Can't the compiler enter the if statement?

Tags: c++

it's a simple time conversion code. Question is:

Given a time in 12-hour AM/PM format, convert it to military (24-hour) time.

**Note:** Midnight is 12:00:00AM on a 12-hour clock, and 00:00:00 on a 24-hour clock. Noon is 12:00:00PM on a 12-hour clock, and 12:00:00 on a 24-hour clock.

my code:-

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   char a[10];
   for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
     cin>>a[i];

  if( a[0]== 1 && a[1]== 2 )
   {
       if(a[8]=='A')
        {
           a[0]=0;
           a[1]=0;
        }
   }
  else if(a[8]=='P')
   {
       a[0]+=1;
       a[1]+=2;
   }
  for(int k=0;k<8;k++)
     cout<<a[k];
}
```

BUT when the input is 12:00:00AM it should change it to 00:00:00 but for some reason, it's not entering the first if statement. Even for 12:34:41AM it gives 12:34:41.

I know the error can be really stupid but just help me with this

Comment: `'1'` does not have the value `1`

Comment: For questions like this, were one particular value shows the problem, just set the contents of `a` to the appropriate value. No need for the input loop or the explanation in the text of the question. `char a[] = "12:00:00AM`. That makes it much easier for others to see what you're doing and to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Always simplify your question down as much as possible before submitting it. If it’s a bug report, it will get much more attention.  If it’s a troubleshooting situation, you are likely to find your own answer and never have to ask the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Mat said, integers 0-9 and characters in ASCII do not have a direct mapping. Check [this](http://www.asciitable.com/) out. You can either express your numbers as chars with quotes (so '1' instead of 1) and they will be read as their ASCII values (so '1' will be read as 49) or use the ASCII value directly. I recommend the first approach.

Comment: Don't assume ASCII if you don't need to. Converting a character code for a digit to the corresponding digit is simple and portable: `ch - '0'` works whenever `ch` is one of the value `'0'..'9'` inclusive.

Comment: Peter's approach is even better. That completely skipped my mind.